# exception.getmessage() return null

Tags: java, exception, collections, ejb, entity

I am having trouble adding an object to a collection.

I encountered a java.lang.NullPointerException when I tried adding an object to a collection.

I tested and checked that redemption which is a RedemptionEntity is not null using the if condition as you can see in the code below. It returned "Not NULL!!!!!!!!!"

I went and google that a java.lang.NullPointerException occurs when you tried adding something that is null into a collection. But in this case, I don't think redemption is null. The System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); return me a null.

How do I resolve this issue? Any help here?

```
private Collection<RedemptionEntity> redemptionCollection; 
RedemptionEntity redemption = new RedemptionEntity();
GiftEntity GIFT = em.find(GiftEntity.class, gift);
redemption.create(date, 0);
redemption.setGift(GIFT);
em.persist(redemption);

if (redemption == null) {
                System.out.println("NULL!!!!!!!!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not NULL!!!!!!!!");
            }
            try {
                redemptionCollection.add(redemption); //This line is where the exception occurs...
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: pls post the exception, but i guess redemptionCollection is null

Comment: Do some where `new` of redemptionCollection before using it. I mean initialize object before using it.

Comment: I took a quick look at the javadoc for a Collection, because I've never used it before.  It seems it is an interface ,should you be using something else?  The interface was likely not instantiated the way you thought it was

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A3dmwN2z <- Here's the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is an interface. Use ArrayList or another List type for initialisiation.

```
ArrayList<RedemptionEntity> col = new ArrayList<RedemptionEntity> ();
```

or

```
Collection<RedemptionEntity> col = new ArrayList<RedemptionEntity> ();
```

Answer (score 1):

did you initialize your Collection?

```
 private Collection<RedemptionEntity> redemptionCollection = new ArrayList<RedemptionEntity>();
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use one of the classes that implements Collection Interface:
Set, List, Map, SortedSet, SortedMap, HashSet, TreeSet, ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector, Collections, Arrays, AbstractCollection